Build a simple project using gn
I am trying to use gn to build a simple C++ project. However when I run gn gen out I see this message:
ERROR Can't find source root.
I could not find a ".gn" file in the current directory or any parent,
and the --root command-line argument was not specified.

I was able to build the examples/simple_build example under the gn source tree without a problem. I was expecting similar results with my own sample created from scratch.

I suppose the obvious question is, do you have a .gn file in the current directory or a parent directory? The next question might be whether examples/simple_build has the same? Those two questions might answer your question. If there is something more complex going on, then at the very least we need to know the answers to those two questions.

Just to mention: On *ix OSes, the prefix . is used to hide files from ls. You have to use e.g. ls -a to show them.
